# Gulp-jade не компилируется в html

Tags: html, gulp, jade

Есть 3 файла:
head.jade

```
meta(charset="utf-8")
```

footer.jade

```
    footer
          p
```

index.jade

```
doctype html
html
     head
        include parts/head
    body
        include parts/footer
```

При компиляции получаю ошибку:

```
Warning: missing space before text for line 1 of jade file "/media/g-dogg/DATA/Web_Projects/MyIzm/src/tpl/parts/head.jade"
Warning: missing space before text for line 1 of jade file "/media/g-dogg/DATA/Web_Projects/MyIzm/src/tpl/parts/footer.jade"

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: /media/g-dogg/DATA/Web_Projects/MyIzm/src/tpl/parts/footer.jade:2
    1|  footer
  > 2|      p

unexpected token "indent"
```

Уже перерыл все, что мог, не могу понять. что нужно ему.
Прошу помощи

Comment: Скорее всего ругается на большой отступ у тэга `p` в файле `footer.jade`, сделайте во всех файлах все отступы одинаковыми

Comment: В том и проблема, что я проверил и выровнял все отступы, везде использую табы. Редактор sublime text 3, ОС - linux. После тэгов пробелов нет.

Comment: @GhostDogg дело не в том, табы у вас или пробелы. В footer 1 уровень отступов лишний, т.е. их там вообще не должно быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых я не знаю, как вы используете jade, если его давно переименовали в pug. Я покажу на примере pug. У меня лично всё скомпилировалось без ошибок. Вот [архив с исходниками](https://yadi.sk/d/vUsjlxMm33YwNm). Сначала устанавливаете pug глобально: `npm i pug-cli -g`, затем компилируете: `pug index.pug`. у меня на выходе получился такой html: `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body><footer><p></p></footer></body></html>`.

По всей видимости у вас лишние отступы в footer.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Переименование в pug я "мимо ушей" пропустил. Значит , внесу изменения в свой скрипты автосборки и протестирую.